# create custom core service in angular

Tags: angularjs

The document of angularjs shows how to create a service of your own module like this

```
angular.module("mymodule", []).service("myService", service);
```

my question is how can I create service like core service like $http ? I try the following, it does not work?

```
angular.module("ng").service("$http2", service);
```

Thanks

Comment: (1) Precisely what do you mean by "core" services in Angular JS?  (2) In what way doesn't it work?  Might it not work because you misspelled the name of the "module" function?

Comment: Is this wise? I don't think messing with the internals of angular is good thing. A better way is to bundle all your "core" services in a single module and link that to myModule

Answer (score 2):

Your module spelling is wrong, other than that it is working fine

```
angular.module("ng").service("$http2", service);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mGMru/)